# How to merge kubectl config file with ~/.kube/config?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a simple `kubectl` command to take a `kubeconfig` file (that contains a cluster+context+user) and merge it into the ~/.kube/config file as an additional context?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Do this:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:~/someotherconfig 
kubectl config view --flatten
```

You can then pipe that out to a new file if needed.

Comment: with pipe `KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/this-config:~/.kube/other-config kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/config`

Comment: That pipe is safe for brand new kubeconfigs, but make sure to *not* merge the contents of a previously existing `~/.kube/config` and a new `other-config` back into `~/.kube/config`; the redirection will truncate the destination before reading it, and you will only see the output of `other-config`.

Comment: Wow, I was thinking to manually merge the two files, but this is insane.

Comment: Advice: check that there is no name conflict in the settings before merging. For example, if your users.name happens to be the same in the config files, kubectl will pick up the first one. Thus, authentication will fail for some of your clusters.

Comment: @talarczykco Dang. Should've seen your comment sooner. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Or you can use `sponge` from `moreutils`: `KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/this-config:~/.kube/other-config kubectl config view --flatten | sponge > ~/.kube/config`

Comment: `--minify` "Remove all information not used by current-context from the output"

Comment: File order matters in KUBECONFIG. Current context is set from the first file in the list.

Comment: another way to do this is a two-step process with a temp file - `KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/this-config:~/.kube/other-config kubectl config view --flatten > tmp.yaml ; mv tmp.yaml ~/.kube/config`

Answer (score 56):

If you find yourself doing this a lot... There is now also the `krew` plugin package manager for `kubectl`.

The `krew` plugin "[konfig](https://github.com/corneliusweig/konfig)" can help you manage your `~/.kube/config` file.

Using the `konfig` plugin the syntax will be:

`kubectl konfig import -s new.yaml`

To install `krew`: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew

To install `konfig`: `kubectl krew install konfig`

Comment: Where does this plugin come from? It's throwing errors and I cannot find a repo to report them to.

Comment: @Routhinator Here's the repo: https://github.com/corneliusweig/konfig - [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew-index/blob/master/plugins.md) are details on how plugins are indexed.

Comment: Krew is not available on Windows

Comment: Krew exist for Windows: https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/

Comment: krew exists for windows, the konfig plugin does not.

❯ kubectl krew install konfig

Updated the local copy of plugin index.

Installing plugin: konfig
W1211 23:50:25.760315    4452 install.go:164] failed to install plugin "konfig": plugin "konfig" does not offer installation for this platform
failed to install some plugins: [konfig]: plugin "konfig" does not offer installation for this platform
Error: exit status 1

Answer (score 35):

### Using multiple `kubeconfigs` at once

Sometimes you have a bunch of small **kubeconfig** files (e.g. one per cluster) but you want to use them all at once, with tools like `kubectl` or [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) that work with multiple contexts at once.

To do that, you need a “merged” **kubeconfig** file. In the section ***"Merging kubeconfig files"*** below, we explain how you can merge the **kubeconfigs** into a single file, but you can also merge them *in-memory*.

By specifying multiple files in `KUBECONFIG` environment variable, you can temporarily stitch **kubeconfig** files together and use them all in `kubectl` .

```sh
#
# Kubeconfig in-memory merge
#
export KUBECONFIG=file1:file2
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2

#
# For your example
# merging your kubeconfig file w/ $HOME/.kube/config (w/ cp backup)
#
cp $HOME/.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config.backup.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S)
KUBECONFIG= $HOME/.kube/config:file2: kubectl config view --merge --flatten > \
~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig && mv ~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
```

### Merging kubeconfig files

Since **kubeconfig** files are structured YAML files, you can’t just append them to get one big **kubeconfig** file, but `kubectl` can help you merge these files:

```sh
#
# Merging your kubeconfig file w/ $HOME/.kube/config (w/ cp backup)
#
cp $HOME/.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config.backup.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S)
KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config:file2:file3 kubectl config view --merge --flatten > \
~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig && mv ~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
```

### Extracting a context from a kubeconfig file

Let’s say you followed the before **merging kubeconfig files** and have a merged **kubeconfig** file in `$HOME/.kube/config`. Now you want to extract a cluster’s information to a portable **kubeconfig** file that only has the parts you need to connect to that cluster.

Run:

```
KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config kubectl config view \
    --minify --flatten --context=context-1 > $HOME/.kube/config-context-1

#
# using --kubeconfig flag
#
kubectl get pods --kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/config-context-1

#
# or 
# using `KUBECONFIG` environment variable
#
KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config-context-1 kubectl get pods

#
# or 
# keep using kubeconfig file at $HOME/.kube/config (which has the merged context)
#
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
```

In this command, we extract data about `context-1` from `$HOME/.kube/config` to `config-context-1` file. The `--minify` flag allows us to extract only info about that context, and the `--flatten` flag allows us to keep the credentials unredacted.

**ref article:** https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/

Answer (score 14):

If you want to merge two config files in a single one

I found this way (not sure if this is the simplest)

```
# Add the two config files to the env var
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:~/Desktop/configFile2.yaml

# Review that you have two configurations in one view
kubectl config view

# View the raw config and output to a new file
kubectl config view --raw > /tmp/config
```

Then copy the new config file where you want, also do not forget to `unset KUBECONFIG` the env variable

Comment: thanks, kubectl config view --flatten  didn't work for me, but kubectl config view --raw did

Comment: simple answer,  there will be current-context per file. what will happen to that current-context? which context will be chosen as current-context in that final file?

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN good question, I think the order matters. You should try to see if the first file has precedence.

Comment: yes, "current-context" in the first file made into the merged config file.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible, follow the steps:

create a backup from your config file:
`cp ~/.kube/config-bkp`

create a file with your new config file:
`vi ~/.kube/new-config`

merge them into config:
`KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:~/.kube/new-config kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/config`

To see the available contexts use:
`kubectl config get-contexts`

To change the context use:
`kubectl config use-context YOUR-CONTEXT-NAME`

Answer (score 4):

You can follow these instruction if you want to have some structure in your `~/.kube` directory.

1. Add the following snippet to your `~/.bashrc`
2. Add config files under `~/.kube/config.d` separately.
3. call `update_kubeconfigs`, or open new terminal

`update_kubeconfigs` just looks at `~/.kube/config.d` directory and if there were any files newer than the current config file under `~/.kube/config`, it updates it.

```bash
function update_kubeconfigs() {
  [ ! -d "$HOME/.kube/config.d" ] && mkdir $HOME/.kube/config.d -p -v
  # Will run only if there are new files in the config directory
  local new_files=$(find $HOME/.kube/config.d/ -newer $HOME/.kube/config -type f | wc -l)
  if [[ $new_files -ne "0" ]]; then
    local current_context=$(kubectl config current-context) # Save last context
    local kubeconfigfile="$HOME/.kube/config"               # New config file
    cp -a $kubeconfigfile "${kubeconfigfile}_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"  # Backup
    local kubeconfig_files="$kubeconfigfile:$(ls $HOME/.kube/config.d/* | tr '\n' ':')"
    KUBECONFIG=$kubeconfig_files kubectl config view --merge --flatten > "$HOME/.kube/tmp"
    mv "$HOME/.kube/tmp" $kubeconfigfile && chmod 600 $kubeconfigfile
    export KUBECONFIG=$kubeconfigfile
    kubectl config use-context $current_context --namespace=default
  fi
}

# This will call each time you source .bashrc, remove it if you want to call it manually each time
update_kubeconfigs
```

Removing files form `~/.kube/confing.d` will not invoke the script again. Also as @rafaelrezend pointed out, checkout for name conflicts in the config files, that might cause issues.

[Github gist](https://gist.github.com/rzjfr/f46e25829492cdf6ce9eb3a28a712acc) includes a fix for updating credentials

Answer (score 3):

Since I have [many Kubernetes conf files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) in the `~/.kube` directory, I simply chain them tot the `KUBECONFIG` env variable in the `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
for conf in ~/.kube/*.conf; do
    export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:$conf
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Zsh users can use a `=(...)` process substitution to generate a temporary merged configuration file, and copy it to `~/.kube/config` all in one line:

```
cp =(KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:~/.kube/config.other kubectl config view --flatten) ~/.kube/config
```

Going a step further, we can hold the configuration file in our system clipboard and use a nested process substitution that reads it. Just make sure that the clipboard content is the actual configuration file before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
cp =(KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:<(pbpaste) kubectl config view --flatten) ~/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash you can use this to simply add the configs:

```
function kmerge() {
 DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
 KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:$1 kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/mergedkub && mv ~/.kube/config ~/.kube/config-$DATE && mv ~/.kube/mergedkub ~/.kube/config
}
```

Then just use "kmerge $newConfigfile" to add this.
Be aware the clusternames etc. should be different from existing config entries!

Answer (score 1):

Going forward, I do not recommend merging kubeconfig files using kubectl.

- it is a manual effort as seen above (set environment variables etc.)
- has the disadvantage that when using this context via "kubectl
  config use-context" it WRITES the current context to the kubeconfig file. Thus,
  this influences other terminal sessions that use a context from the same
  kubeconfig file (they all suddenly point to the same context).

Instead, I would recommend using a tool that circumvents such issues by e.g recursively search & displays all available contexts for kubeconfig files and works on a temporary copy.

Checkout [kubeswitch](https://github.com/danielfoehrKn/kubeswitch) (the tool I wrote to deal with > 1000 kubeconfig files) and [this section explaining how it works](https://github.com/danielfoehrKn/kubeswitch#how-it-works).

If you look for a tool that also does namespace switching and other related things, take a look at "kubie".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @talarczykco on the top answer, piping back to the same `~/.kube/config` will only write the second file and you will **lose** the original content!

Here is a safer way to first capture the full output then pipe.

**Note** must surround the variable `kubeconfig` with `"` otherwise you lose all newlines!

```
konfig=$(KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:new-config.yaml kubectl config view --flatten)

echo "$konfig" > ~/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a CLI tool I can highly recommend: KubeCM, which is also able to merge, switch, add...

```
kubecm add -f ./your_new_config
```

You would be asked either to merge into `~/.kube/config` or create a .yml file in your current folder.

https://github.com/sunny0826/kubecm

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically merge multiple config files in you .bashrc:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/Users/<user>/.kube/config:/Users/<user>/.kube/other.config
source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

After fresh source, verify:

```
kubectl config view
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep the yaml files for each cluster separate and then combine them with this python script:

```py
import argparse
import yaml
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('files', metavar='YAMLFILES', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()

y = {'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Config', 'clusters': [],'contexts': [],
    'current-context': None, 'preferences': {}, 'users': []}
for a in args.files:
    f = yaml.load(a, Loader=yaml.Loader)
    y['clusters'].append(f['clusters'][0])
    y['contexts'].append(f['contexts'][0])
    y['users'].append(f['users'][0])
    y['current-context'] = f['contexts'][0]['name']

print(yaml.dump(y, Dumper=yaml.Dumper))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the script provided by [rzjfr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65459878/7465577) to work on Mac zsh:

```
update_kubeconfigs() {
  ### Update kubeconfig file based on the individual files on the $config_dir
  local config_dir="${1:-$HOME/.kube/config.d}"
  local backup_files_to_keep="${2:-10}"
  local config_file="$HOME/.kube/config"
  local newer_files current_context kubeconfig_files
  ###

  if [[ ! -d "$config_dir" ]]; then mkdir -p -v "$config_dir"; fi
  if [[ -f "$config_file" ]]; then
    newer_files=$(find "$config_dir" -newer "$config_file" -type f)
  else
    newer_files=$(find "$config_dir" -type f)
  fi

  # Only if there were files newer than the existing config_file
  if [[ -n "$newer_files" ]]; then
    current_context=$(kubectl config current-context) # Save last context

    # Backup existing config file and remove old backups
    cp -a "$config_file" "${config_file}_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")"
    find "${config_file%/*}" -maxdepth 1 -name "config_*" -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"' _ {} \; | sort -n | tail -n "+$backup_files_to_keep" | xargs rm -f

    # Remove contexts if they have changed to force updates
    # Split the string into an array using parameter expansion
    newer_files=("${(@f)newer_files}")
    for file in "${newer_files[@]}"; do
      echo "Checking if context exists for $file"
      context_name=$(kubectl config get-contexts --kubeconfig "$file" --no-headers | awk '{print $2}')
      context_cluster=$(kubectl config get-contexts --kubeconfig "$file" --no-headers | awk '{print $3}')
      context_user=$(kubectl config get-contexts --kubeconfig "$file" --no-headers | awk '{print $4}')
      if kubectl config get-contexts | grep -q "$context_name"; then
        kubectl config delete-context "$context_name"
        kubectl config unset "contexts.$context_name"
        kubectl config unset "clusters.$context_cluster"
        kubectl config unset "users.$context_user"
      fi
    done

    # Create a new config file
    kubeconfig_files="$config_file:$(find "$HOME/.kube/config.d/" -type f -print | tr '\n' ':')"
    KUBECONFIG="$kubeconfig_files" kubectl config view --merge --flatten > "$HOME/.kube/tmp"

    # install -m 600 "$HOME/.kube/tmp" $config_file
    mv "$HOME/.kube/tmp" "$config_file" && chmod 600 "$config_file"
    export KUBECONFIG=$config_file
    kubectl config use-context "$current_context" --namespace=default
  fi
}

# Merge kubeconfig
update_kubeconfigs "$HOME/.kube/config.d" 10 # keep 10 most recent backup
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my improvement based on the answer of @joost-döbken

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71681738/5243543

```bash
# Kubernetes config merge
unset KUBECONFIG

for conf in ~/.kube/config*; do
    # -z means is empty
    if [ -z "$KUBECONFIG" ]; then
        export KUBECONFIG=$conf
        continue
    fi

    export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:$conf
done
```