# Disabling context-switching that happens with kubectl config view --flatten

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a command-line utility to start/stop VMs that I am extending to managing Kubernetes clusters. It can save the `kubeconfig` currently, as well as merge a new configuration into a user's existing `~/.kube/config` - but the command I am using (from [How to merge kubectl config file with ~/.kube/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184125/how-to-merge-kubectl-config-file-with-kube-config)) also switches the active context:

```
KUBECONFIG=<temporary_path_to_newly_created_config>:~/.kube/config kubectl config view --flatten`
```

Is there a way to prevent the active context from switching unless I want it to? Am I using the wrong command with `kubectl config view --flatten` and is there a merging option that makes no changes to the active context?

Comment: what if you switch the order `KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:<new_config_path>`?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta thought of that before I asked - same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `kubectl` behaves as it does.

1. Actually there is no systemwide `current-context` value. You might have several `current-context` values in the kubeconfig files specified in the `$KUBECONFIG` variable or another files specified with the parameter `--kubeconfig=`.
2. There is default kubeconfig file `~/.kube/config` that `kubectl` uses when the `$KUBECONFIG` variable is empty and parameter `--kubeconfig=` is not provided.
3. Every time you start `kubectl`, it reads and merges values from the kubeconfig files to build its configuration for the **current** run.
4. While merging kubeconfig files, among conflicting values the one from the **first** file wins.
5. When you direct `kubectl` to `use-context` with the command 
   `KUBECONFIG=config1:config2 kubectl config use-context my_context`, 
   it saves context into the file listed **first** in the `$KUBECONFIG` variable (config1).

Hence it’s not entirely accurate to say that kubectl "switches active context". It saves context **to where you point** and reads [possibly another] context **from where you point**. The `current-context` for the **current** `kubectl` run is set based on its command-line parameters, contents of the kubeconfig files and the order they are listed in the `$KUBECONFIG` variable.

Now back to the question.

Q:

> Is there a way to prevent the active context from switching unless I
>   want it to? and is there a merging option that makes no changes to the
>   active context?

A:

There is no way to prevent the "active context" from switching because the `current-context` stored in the default and other kubeconfig files is assigned as "active" for the **current** run **each time** `kubectl` is launched. Also, `kubectl` shouldn't be considered as a plain text parsing & merging tool.

Speaking about **default** configuration in the particular case you've described, to re-use the previously used or preferred context or the one you believe "is current", you should list the kubeconfig file with that context **the first** in the `$KUBECONFIG` variable:

```
KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:new_config_to_merge kubectl config view --flatten > ...
```

NOTE. If **none** of the kubeconfig files contain **not empty** `current-context` value, the error will appear: `error: current-context is not set`.

Please see [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Use [`kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration)

or

## 2. Install [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx)

The second option will make your life so much easier, of course for both solution you have to set your config files in `KUBECONFIG`

Comment: So either way I'll have to run a second command to (re)set the cluster? No option in the config combination operation to prevent the switch?