# How can I load 2 (or more) different kubeconfig in python3 kubernetes client?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have 2 kubernetes cluster in 2 region

2 kubeconfig file are **kube1.kubeconfig** and **kube2.kubeconfig**

I'm using python to call to kubernetes cluster using kubernetes-client python

I see it will load the config from the env **KUBECONFIG**

but my program need to push API to 2 different cluster

So are there anyway to solve that problems:

Code for examples:

```py
if <condiation a>:
  (load kube1.kubeconfig)
  (process my code)
elif <condition b>:
  (load kube2.kubeconfig)
  (process my code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `kubectl` the usual way is to merge all `kubeconfig` files into one `kubeconfig` files and then use the context API to switch between contexts/clusters `kubectl config use-context my-context-1` or `kubectl config use-context my-context-2`. Looking at [python kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) it looks like you can do the same:

- To merge `kubeconfig` files you can have a look at [How to merge kubectl config file with ~/.kube/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184125/how-to-merge-kubectl-config-file-with-kube-config).
- To change context with [python kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) you can have a look at [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/ceaf188498bd43577b1bec72cc4e839be2379632/examples/pick_kube_config_context.py#L26).

Answer (score 6):

You can create separate clients from different `kubeconfig`s using `new_client_from_config_dict` function. This gives you 2 isolated clients without having to load the config globally:

```py
def make_k8s_client(kubeconfig: dict) -> kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api:
    api_client = kubernetes.config.new_client_from_config_dict(kubeconfig)
    return kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(api_client)
    
with open('kubeconfig.yaml') as f:
    kubeconfig = yaml.safe_load(f)

k8s_1 = make_k8s_client(kubeconfig)

# a different config

with open('kubeconfig2.yaml') as f:
    kubeconfig2 = yaml.load(f)

k8s_2 = make_k8s_client(kubeconfig2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The python Kubernetes library provides the following:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/09dbbe521e203634154764b903208bb28cd70f9d/config/kube_config.py#L796

```
config.load_kube_config(config_file=None, context=None, client_configuration=None, persist_config=True)
```

You can use that like this:

```
from kubernetes import config

config.load_kube_config(config_file='./kubeconfig_file_path1')
# now you can do what you need to do with this cluster

config.load_kube_config(config_file='./kubeconfig_file_path2')
# now you can do what you need to do with this other cluster
```

You can also specify which context from a kubeconfig file to be used in case there are multiple contexts within the same kubeconfig file.

So this is another approach if you want to keep the kubeconfig files separate.