# Unable to "get" my calico node using calicoctl

Tags: get, nodes, calico

I am trying to examine my node to potentially fix my nodes, but the command "get" is failing.

the error is

```
Failed to create Calico API client... error parsing document: fields in document are not recognized or are in the wrong location: clusters, contexts, current-context, preferences, users
```

Is there another way to "get" my nodes in calico?

More information:

I am able to "get" my node using kubectl

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: "0"
    projectcalico.org/IPv4Address: 192.241.129.100/24
    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-10T19:33:06Z"
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    kubernetes.io/hostname: artemis
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
    node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane: ""
    node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:beta.kubernetes.io/arch: {}
          f:beta.kubernetes.io/os: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/arch: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/hostname: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/os: {}
      f:status:
        f:addresses:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Hostname"}:
            .: {}
            f:address: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"InternalIP"}:
            .: {}
            f:address: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:allocatable:
          .: {}
          f:cpu: {}
        ...
```

I have one master and two worker nodes. All pods and nodes appear to be healthy. Each pairing is able to ping both of the other nodes, but each is failing at a network test.

calicoctl shows all nodes as being "up" when viewed from the other nodes but the command "get" is failing.

```
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
|  PEER ADDRESS   |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |   SINCE    |    INFO     |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| 143.198.57.235  | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-03-10 | Established |
| 143.110.149.114 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 2021-03-10 | Established |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------+------------+-------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been playing around with multiple config files.  Whereas kubectl will recognize multiple config files for testing purposes, calicoctl will not.  I merged my config files using instructions found here:

[How to merge kubectl config file with ~/.kube/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184125/how-to-merge-kubectl-config-file-with-kube-config#46184649)

Fixed!